# Batch script to prefix file names

Tags: batch-file, file-io, prefix

I am trying to rename files in a batch script like this:

```
rename %FOLDER%\* 1-*
```

but when I run the script It overwrites the first two characters of the original names with the prefix "1-" instead of adding it to the beginning of the file names. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename will just rename the file, you would need to call the file name as a variable after the prefix. The below is what ended up working.

```
cd %folder%
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "1-%%a"
```

Comment: it returned: The system cannot find the file D:\folder"\*.*'.

Comment: sorry I accidentally hit **'** when I was typing it up try it again.

Comment: Finally solved it by changing directory to %folder% and running your second command:
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "1-%%a"
thanks man!

Comment: No problem, mind accepting my answer so I get credit? Click the little check mark. I will update my answer to show your fix.

Answer (score 1):

try this as a starting point

```
@echo off 
for %%a in (%folder%\*) do (
  echo ren "%%~fa" "1-%%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: Maskedplant was faster, he deserves +1

Comment: it did echo the correct syntax like so: ren "D:\folder\file one.txt" "D:\folder\1-file one.txt"
however if i execute without the echo it gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect." error..

Comment: @User You are right, I copied the code from a MOVE command, and the syntax does not work for RENAME. Edited and, hopefully, fixed.